# Why typescript function overload adds undefined type?

Tags: typescript, overloading

I'm expecting `data` argument to be `string` type not `string | undefined` in `type === 'scheduled'` case. Why this is happening? Is there a way to make it `string` type?

```
function foo(type: 'live'): string;
function foo(type: 'scheduled', data: string): string;
function foo(type: 'live' | 'scheduled', data?: string): string {

    switch (type) {
        case 'live':
            return '';
        case 'scheduled':
            return data; // expecting for this to be string type not string | undefined
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUUCeAHApgLkQHIAbGAN1yIEpCBnKAJxjAHMBuAKFElgWVQYcBYnQgALXABMQJaUQA0iKQEMoK+kxataiBszZce0eEhToseQqQpVEAH1ETps+UtXqA-JoM6f2xABvTk5EML0AdxgoCUQhPGog0PCUiBU6XGIySiJ8ZJSCxEZcKBBGJCIiLkKwtIynSRk5KVz8mrDi0vLlNRV2RAB6AcRcAA88EzYBRkQocRg6WbhEACNM-QDLTLA4KD0tKcdwKVxgFmk2gF9OS6A)

Comment: you set `data?: string`, so type of data is `string | undefined`.

Comment: *Inside* the function only the last type definition is used, so the type of `type` is `'live' | 'scheduled'` and the type of `data` is `string | undefined`. Given that you have additional information, you could do e.g. `return data as string`.

Answer (score 1):

It's weird indeed, but you can use discriminated unions which work better:

```
function foo(t: { type: 'live' } | { type: 'scheduled', data: string }): string {
    switch (t.type) {
        case 'live':
            return '';
        case 'scheduled':
            t.data;
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUUBciDeioCeADgKbYDkANjAG4nmIC+iAPrvsWYuQM4QAWJACYhKw8gBpEQgIZQZ2HlABOMMAHMmASkUq1mnAChEJxDwDuMKAMQYAdIVJbcx024gyeJbtTrlMrm5BiMokUCDKSOTkANyBQR5e3HyCImJC-vHBJlB2svJxboyGjEA)

Comment: This solution also has some gotchas to it. `type` can't be deconstructed if you want to use it in switch statement [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUUBciDeioCeADgKbYDkANjAG4nmIC+iAPrvsWYuQM4QAWJACYhKw8gBpEQgIZQZ2HlABOMMAHMmASkUq1mnAChEJxBARL2hUk0QBefAG5jplyZ4B3GFAGIMnLVw3UxMIGR4Sbmo6ckxgkJDlEigQZSRycmcE0zCI7j5BETEhWPjsxCSUtPwAOll5LNNGQ0YgA)